# Python Merge two nested dictionary keeping all items

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I have python 3.5. Trying to merge two nested dictionary and get result set as "union all" of both dict. Here is my code

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import json
from itertools import chain
d = ''
d1 = ''

d1 = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

def CreateDataSet(koin, order, key, value):
    global d, d1
    d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
    d[koin][order][key] = value
    d1 = dict(chain(d.items(), d1.items()))

CreateDataSet('BTC', 'Buy', 'BTZeB', 76000)
CreateDataSet('LTC', 'Buy', 'LTKoB', 6000)
CreateDataSet('LTC', 'sell', 'LTZeS', 6050)
CreateDataSet('OMG', 'Buy', 'OGDeB', 9000)
CreateDataSet('OMG', 'Buy', 'OGKoB', 9100)
print(json.dumps(d1))
```

I am expecting result like this -

```
{
"BTC": {
    "Buy": {
        "BTZeB": 76000
    }
},
"LTC": {
    "Buy": {
        "LTKoB": 6000
    },
    "sell": {
        "LTKoS": 6050
    }
},
"OMG": {
    "Buy": {
        "OGDeB": 9000,
        "OGKoB": 9100
    }
}
}
```

But, I am getting like this -

```
{
"LTC": {
    "Buy": {
        "LTKoB": 6000
    }
},
"OMG": {
    "Buy": {
        "OGDeB": 9000
    }
},
"BTC": {
    "Buy": {
        "BTZeB": 76000
    }
}
}
```

Any other method would be appreciated. Meanwhile, i am also trying to figure out how can this be done using for loop.

Comment: your expected result is made of a dictionary with duplicate keys!!!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes. Or if i can collate values of same key in once set.

Comment: @liliscent i tried this as well - d1 = {**d, **d1} . But same output.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question to show expected output then

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Done

Comment: @imtiyaz283 upvote: Done. Now I think the question is answerable

Comment: I really don't understand all the downvotes after the edit. OP provided a [mcve] with code & expected output. This isn't fair

Answer (score 1):

you're overcomplexifying this. Only 1 dict is required with all the defaulting of defaulting, which creates the expected result without effort:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import json

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

def CreateDataSet(koin, order, key, value):
    d[koin][order][key] = value

CreateDataSet('BTC', 'Buy', 'BTZeB', 76000)
CreateDataSet('LTC', 'Buy', 'LTKoB', 6000)
CreateDataSet('LTC', 'sell', 'LTZeS', 6050)
CreateDataSet('OMG', 'Buy', 'OGDeB', 9000)
CreateDataSet('OMG', 'Buy', 'OGKoB', 9100)
print(json.dumps(d, indent=True)) #bracket change
```

result:

```
{
 "BTC": {
  "Buy": {
   "BTZeB": 76000
  }
 },
 "LTC": {
  "sell": {
   "LTZeS": 6050
  },
  "Buy": {
   "LTKoB": 6000
  }
 },
 "OMG": {
  "Buy": {
   "OGKoB": 9100,
   "OGDeB": 9000
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: i was overthinking it since last two days. Thanks a ton Jean.